# Angular + PHP не могу добиться работы скрипта

Tags: php, angularjs, http

Есть простой пример формы [отправки данных](http://metanit.com/web/angular/3.8.php).
Не могу его воспроизвести у себя на локалке. Ангуляр установлен, вроде бы все подключено. При нажатии на кнопку обновляется страница, форма стирается и ничего не происходит.
В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: В консоль (в инструментах разработчика) смотрели, ошибок нету?

Comment: в source вот такая ошибка есть http://shot.qip.ru/00Qjkn-6SwgAVNLv/

Comment: Так вроде все нормально проходит http://shot.qip.ru/00Qjkn-2SwgAVNLw/

Comment: залил на сервак возможно так будет проще проанализировать http://p687188m.bget.ru/

Comment: Откуда вы взяли `var app = module.exports = require('appjs');` ? Это вообще серверный код (`nodejs`)

Comment: Ох если честно, где то вычитал что так должно сработать, я что только уже не пробовал. Советы какие дать можете либо направить в нужное русло? Буду премного благодарен.